# C# Arrays - Conversion/Copy

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I need an array of the same dimensions (to hold values 0 or 1) as an argument to a function which may be of any rank and any type. The result array will contain 0 for failure and 1 for success (I could use Boolean) arising from a process. How can I create the result array?

Comment: What is the specific requirement? Did you try anything? Creating a boolean array of a specific size maybe?

Comment: This seems like an insane requirement. For failure, you should throw an exception.

Comment: @IanNewson: It's not insane. There are times when you have a list of things you want to do, and you want to report which of them could be done. Exceptions are often the best solution for failure situations, but not always.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Array.CreateInstance`:

```
private static Array CreateArray(Array array)
{
    List<int> dimensions = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Rank; i++)
    {
        dimensions.Add(array.GetLength(i));
    }
    return Array.CreateInstance(typeof(bool), dimensions.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was searching for (for several hours!). Thank you very much.

Comment: If this is the solution to your problem mark it as such so the other people would know :]